# Parent class method call parent method, not child class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Is there a way for a child class method to prevent the parent from calling the another child method, but instead call the parent's method?

Here's the code sample I'm referring to:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        return 'Af'

    def ff(self, var):
        return var + 'ff ' + self.f()

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        return 'Bf'

    def ff(self):
        return super().ff('B')

print(B().ff())
```

The output is `Bff Bf`
I want it to be: `Bff Af`

In other words, when `B.f()` it's called, I would like to redirect the call to `A.f()` if the calling class is `A`.
And if the calling class is `B` then call `B.f()`.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know, but that sounds like the opposite of how conventional OO is supposed to work.

Comment: @melpomene Indeed. It's just that I'm trying to preserve the same naming convention on all the class methods throughout all inheriting subclasses.

Comment: If you use inheritance, `ff` in `B` should take the same parameters `self, var` as in `A`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you haven't designed `A` for inheritance. For method overriding to work cleanly and without unpredictable side effects, you need to carefully think about *and document* what methods depend on what other methods.

Also, you have a serious Liskov substitution violation in the fact that `B.ff` takes 0 arguments when `A.ff` takes one.

You have three primary options here. One is to use composition instead:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
    def f(self):
        return 'Bf'
    def ff(self):
        return self.a.ff('B')
```

Now `B.f` has no effect on either class's `ff`. Given the mismatching `A.ff` and `B.ff` signatures, having `B` inherit from `A` is probably a bad idea even if you clean up `A` to support inheritance better.

Option 2 is to decide that `f` is a hook for customizing `ff`. In this case, you keep the current `A` implementation and behavior, and if child classes want to customize `ff` separately, they need to override that in a way that doesn't depend on `A.ff`:

```
class B(A):
    def f(self):
        return 'Bf'
    def ff(self):
        return 'Bff ' + super().f()
```

Option 3 is to decide that overriding `f` should not affect `ff`. In that case, `A.ff` needs to invoke `A.f` in a way that is not affected by overrides. For example, `A.ff` could call `f` as `A.f` instead of `self.f`:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        return 'Af'

    def ff(self, var):
        return var + 'ff ' + A.f(self)
```

Then your existing `B` will work as intended. This option is probably the runner-up after option 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by not using inheritance (and using composition instead):

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        return 'Af'

    def ff(self, var):
        return var + 'ff ' + self.f()

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

    def f(self):
        return 'Bf'

    def ff(self):
        return self.a.ff('B')

print(B().ff())
```

Output:

```
Bff Af
```

Comment: Unfortunately composition is not an option. Only interested in inheritance since the rest of the `B` class utilizes everything inherited from A (and others).

Comment: @slybloty OK, now your question has become an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Now you just threw me in a confusion loop.

Comment: @slybloty You're not asking about your real problem (X), you're asking about your attempt at a solution (Y), which doesn't work (but you think if it did, it would solve X). The problem is that Y doesn't really make sense and we can't give useful solutions because we don't know the hidden constraints imposed by X. It would probably be better if you could take a step back and explain X. It may turn out that Y isn't even the right solution.